# What is the advantage of a single-function-class over a function?

Tags: c++, algorithm, design-patterns

I have often encountered classes with the following structure:

```
class FooAlgorithm {
  public:
    FooAlgorithm(A a, B b);
    void run();
  private:
    A _a;
    B _b;
};
```

So classes with only one public member function that are also only run once.
Is there any advantage in any case over a single free function `foo(A a, B b)`?
The latter option is easier to call, potentially has less header dependencies and also has  much less boilerplate in the header.

Comment: What does the `run` function do?  Who calls it?  Is it a requirement that the class has a `run()` function?  Maybe a template function requires that the type being used has an available `run()` function?  Your simpler version of `foo(A a, B b)` doesn't have any of those traits.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is that you can create a class and store the parameters in it. Then pass it around, store it, do whatever. Then you run it once it makes sense.

Comment: Disregarding the obvious (inheritance to derivations), there are places where a *functor* can be incredibly handy, and is nearly always better suited for inline expansion optimization, especially for standard library algorithms. But if this is as you say, under the *severe* restrictions you've claimed, then the very premise of a class seems pointless. The only thing this offers is delayed execution of `run` with previously acquired copied arguments, which may not be around to provide at the point an equitable function would be used, in whatever menagerie this example really resides in.

Comment: The lifecycle of the members is the same as the lifecycle of the object containing it meaning you could e.g. pass the object around in a `std::unique_ptr<FooAlgorithm> logic;` until you finally do `logic->run(); logic.reset();`. Now try to accomplish the same with a function pointer and 2 objects and the whole thing becomes more complex. Especially useful, if execution of the logic and creation of the object happend on different threads...

Answer (score 1):

An object has state that can be set up at object construction time. Then the single member function can be called at a later time, *without knowing anything about how the object was set up*, and the function can refer to the state that was set up earlier. A standalone function cannot do that. Any state must be passed to it as arguments, or be global/static (global/static data is best avoided for a variety of reasons).

An hands-on example is worth a thousand abstract explanations, so here is an exercise. Consider a simple object:

```
struct Obj {
   std::array<std::string, 42> attributes;
};
```

How would you sort a vector of such objects, comparing only the attribute number K (K being a run-time parameter in the range 0..41)? Use `std::sort` and do not use any global or static data. Note how `std::sort` compares two objects: it calls a user-provided comparator, and passes it two objects to be compared, but it knows nothing about the parameter K and cannot pass it along to the comparator.

Comment: Spoiler alert. Most people would implement this using a lambda, but lambda is just syntactic sugar for exactly the kind of object you describe in your question. Lambdas were invented exactly because programmers need such single-use, trow-away objects all the time.

Answer (score 0):

For bigger projects it may be easier to structure your programm using OOP.
For a simple program like yours it is easier to use a single function.

Answer (score 0):

Classes introduce a new dynamic to your program -> Better readability, security, moudularity, re-usability....
functions are used to organize code into blocks.